# declaring an array of pointers in a C header file and assigning value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, header-files

Is it possible to declare an array of pointers and later on initialize either of them and assign a value, in a `C` header file?

```
char *i[2];  
i[0] = "abc";
```

the following does not work.

```
char *x = "def"; // this will, of course.
```

How am I supposed to declare and assign values for an array of pointers?

Comment: Which book on C are you reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with header files. You cannot create a .c file and put in it code like this:

```
char *i[2];  
i[0] = "abc";
```

In C, all code except definitions and initialisations must be inside functions, and your second statement is neither of these - it is an assignment.

An initialisation for your array would look like this:

```
char *i[2] = {"foo","bar"};
```

And that could be put in a header file, but would cause multiple definition errors if the header were used in more than one translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible. But you should **never** declare variables on header files. Do it on **.c** files.

Also, you should initialize `char *` vectors with something like this:

```
char *i[2] = { "ABC", "CDE" };
```

Comment: @Neil: It's technically possible to declare variables in header files.

Comment: @Pablo Blame the OP's formatting and my bad eyesight. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: If by constants you mean `#define` macros, then you can declare them on header files. But keep in mind they're just macros.

Comment: i consider const char pointers also constants. is there any other way of separately instantiating the members of this pointer array, i mean, is it only possible via direct assigment on declaration? thing is, my strings are too large..

Comment: @XXL: you can write an `init` function to initialize your arrays. Otherwise, it's only possible via direct assignment on declaration. There is no executable code outside functions in **C**.

Comment: *Declaring* variables (`extern char *i[2];`) in header files is fine, it's *defining* (`char *i[2];` or `char *i[2] = { "ABC", "CDE" };`) them that's problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
char *i[2] = {"abc", "def"};
```

Though it'll give you a warning unless you make them `const char *`

```
const char *i[2] = {"abc", "def"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code

```
char *i[2];  
i[0] = "abc";
```

doesn't works?? could you post the errors?

I tried this in gcc and vc++ and it works just fine.

You can also go through the tutorial at this link:
http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap9/section2.1.4.html

Excerpts:

> char * nameptr[MAX];
>
> The array, nameptr[], is an array of
>   size MAX, and each element of the
>   array is a character pointer. It is
>   then possible to assign character
>   pointer values to the elements of the
>   array; for example:
>
> nameptr[i] = "John Smith";
>
> The string "John Smith" is placed
>   somewhere in memory by the compiler
>   and the pointer to the string constant
>   is then assigned to nameptr[i].